# How to merge ingress-nginx with existing nginx on worker node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

One worker node has already installed a nginx and listened on port 80. I want to leverage ingress-nginx and keep former service in worker node still working. Is there any way to merge ingress-nginx with existing nginx on worker node?

I'm working on baremetal environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple pods listening on port 80 should not be an issue as they should be in their own network namespaces, unless you explicitly run them with `hostNetwork: true` which in most cases you should not.

For running nginx-ingress on baremetal you should expose it with NodePort Service on predefined ports like ie. 32080 and 32443, which will make your ingress availabe on all the nodes on these ports, and then configure your network so that some IP 80/443 traffic is directed by your loadbalancer to kube nodes on these predefined ports

Comment: You really save me! The `.yaml` file I've downloaded uses `hostPort`.

Answer (score 0):

The ingress-nginx has its own nginx running, it watches the resources at the api-server and update the nginx configuration dynamically, while the nginx uses the static configuration, so they can't be merged together. I guess you can configure ingress to access nginx through ingress-nginx.

Comment: You really inspire me! While configuring ingress-nginx to include extra `.conf` file is a big job,  it's easy to alter my nginx configuration. First I'll use the two annotations `--http-port` and `--https-port` to let ingress-nginx listen on `10080` and `10433`. Then all I need is adding a short configuration to my nginx. For example, when nginx catches traffic for `http://dashboard.myservier.com`, it will pass through to `dashboard.myservier.com:10080`, which can be caught by ingress-nginx. I'll try this later.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: so, why not just throw out the nginx ? It's totally useless in this situation you described.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If I remove nginx, how can I access services that are not orchestrated by kubernetes?

Comment: you can configure sevice and endpoint for those service that are not orchestrated by kubernetes, then ingress-nginx can probe that.

Comment: You're right. I'm novice to kubernetes and I'm following a tutorial. The tutorial doesn't mention endpoint before introducing ingress.
In fact ingress-nginx doesn't conflict with nginx, I encounter this problem because the `ingress-nginx-controller.yaml` file I use configured `hostPort`. Radek 'Goblin' Pieczonka figures out this.